# Recursive nested matching pairs of curly braces in Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string:

```
The {quick} brown fox {jumps {over {deep} the} {sfsdf0} lazy} dog {sdfsdf1 {sdfsdf2}
```

And PHP Regular Expression:

```
/(?=\{((?:[^{}]+|\{(?1)\})+)\})/g
```

It yields the following matches:

```
[5-10]  `quick`
[23-60] `jumps {over {deep} the} {sfsdf} lazy`
[30-45] `over {deep} the`
[36-40] `deep`
[48-54] `sfsdf0`
[76-83] `sdfsdf2`
```

See: http://regex101.com/r/fD3iZ2.

I'm trying to get the equivalent working in Ruby, but I'm having a problem with `(?1)`… resulting in an `undefined group option` error:

```
str = "The {quick} brown fox {jumps {over {deep} the} {sfsdf} lazy} dog {sdfsdf {sdfsdf}"
str.scan /(?=\{((?:[^{}]+|\{(?1)\})+)\})/

SyntaxError: undefined group option: /(?=\{((?:[^{}]+|\{(?1)\})+)\})/
```

See: http://fiddle.re/n6w4n.

Coincidently, I get the same sort of error in Javascript and Python.

My regex foo is nearly exhausted today, any help very much appreciated.

Comment: `?` is a reserved character inside parentheses in JavaScript and Ruby, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: `(?1)` is supposedly accepted in Javascript - it means to recurse the first sub-pattern. Since I'm getting the same error in Ruby, Javascript and Python, I'm assuming the issue is the bracket grouping, not the `?1`.

Comment: Wow - learn something new every day, thanks.  I'll take a look at it.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support recursion. Neither does Python.

Comment: js doesn't support recursion at all, unless using regexp package (third-party - which i never used before). python does support recursion but with the regex package, not re. and both of them are not captured group recursion, only complete pattern recursion

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ruby uses a different syntax for recursion: `\g<1>` replaces `(?1)`. So try

```
(?=\{((?:[^{}]++|\{\g<1>\})++)\})
```

I also made the quantifiers possessive to avoid excessive backtracking in case of unbalanced braces.

```
irb(main):003:0> result = str.scan(/(?=\{((?:[^{}]++|\{\g<1>\})++)\})/)
=> [["quick"], ["jumps {over {deep} the} {sfsdf} lazy"], ["over {deep} the"], 
["deep"], ["sfsdf"], ["sdfsdf"]]
```

Comment: Interestingly, the same syntax you've shown above also works for PHP.

Comment: Too match empty bracket pairs `{}` you could add a `?` after `\g<1>` like this: `(?=\{((?:[^{}]++|\{\g<1>?\})++)\})`