# Regex to exclude expression if in table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I need to capture an expression but only if it is not in a table. I'm using Ruby.

```
hello.
<p>
  <b>  1 capture  </b>
</p>
<table class="tb1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>
        <b> 1 don't capture </b>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p><strong> 2 capture </strong></p>
<table><tr>  <td>  <p>  <b>  2 don't capture  </b>  </p>  </td>  </tr>  </table>
<p>  <b>  3 don't capture  </b>  </p> Some text here...
<p>  <strong>  4 don't capture  </strong> Some text here... </p>
<table fdfdfdfd>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p>  <b>  5 don't capture  </b>  </p>
  </td>
  <table>
    table...
  </table>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The outcome should be:

```
<p>
  <b>  1 capture  </b>
</p>
<p><strong> 2 capture </strong></p>
```

Currently I have this regex: `\n\s*<p>\s*<(strong|b)>(?:(?!</\1>).)+</\1>\s*</p>\s*\n`

Tried a lookahed that excludes expression if there is `</table>` and no `<table.*>` preceding it, but there are some complicated issues with greedy expressions and new-line problems.

**Edit: I know that there are other ways for doing that, but I must know it this is possible or not with regex.**

Comment: use Nokogiri to make life simple...

Comment: using a xml reader and just traversing the document is the way to go here.

Comment: Arup - unfortunately we have some strict rules for installing new gems on production server. Benjamin - Using any kind of xml reader / dom parser is going to be the last resort. I need to be sure it is not possible with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do recursive regex matching. Here's one pointer to a How To: [Rexegg regex-recursion](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html). And there is a SO answer for [Ruby recursive regex matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486686/recursive-nested-matching-pairs-of-curly-braces-in-ruby-regex)